# How to pass the item id to another activity?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I am using Eclipse Java EE IDE Juno, developing an Android apps.

I have a page, ListItem.xml, which contains of a list of items.
For each item click, it will redirect to the same layout of DetailActivity.xml.

Since the item click will refer to the same layout, I wish to ask, how to pass the value of the item click so that each click will retrieve different information from database and display it in the DetailActivity.xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create an `Intent` and send the `itemId` to the next Activity as:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), DetailActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("ITEM_ID", itemId);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: then follow by:
String id = intent.getStringExtra("ITEM_ID");
in DetailActivity?

Comment: Exactly. Be aware that you can only pass serializable objects as `extra` parameters. Since your are passing a simple `String`, it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

Add the id as an extra to the Intent you use to launch the new activity.  Have the new activity read it from the intent it receives at startup.